# How do I unlock the screen when forgotten password?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens, password

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2. My daughter put a screen lock on and doesn't remember the code. How do I unlock it?

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! Try not to explain the problem in the title(your title could have been "daughter locked out of Samsung galaxy 2") :)

Answer (score 1):

If you log on to android device manager, you can send a lock request, allowing you to change the password. Just be sure to change it after!

As a alternative, keep getting it wrong until "forgot password?" and login in via google. It will then let you reset the password

Answer (score 0):

First off the tab. Then 
1. Power key
2. Volume up key
3. Main key

Press same time. After come option then select wip aLL  data . Your tab will reset. 
Rember. After reset you lose all data . Which have in your tab memory.

Comment: There is no "main key" on the tab. Other than volume and power, all keys are software keys. (part of the systemUI)